Why can't this docopt flag be used directly in an if statement?
I'm using docopt to generate a simple --debug flag.
Here's some example code to illustrate the problem (try it in Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docopt/docopt-go"
)

var usage string = `
Usage:
    demo-cli [--debug]

Options:
    --debug  Turn on debug logging
`

func main() {
    opts, _ := docopt.ParseDoc(usage)

    fmt.Printf("Type: %T\n", opts["--debug"])

    if opts["--debug"] {
        fmt.Println("Debug enabled")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Normal logging")
    }
}

I've found a few options (ha) for making this actually work, and I'd be interested to hear how others would do it:

A straight comparison works: if opts["--debug"] == true
Casting directly to bool works: if opts["--debug"].(bool)
Using docopt's recommended helper function works: debug, _ := opts.Bool("--debug")

What I don't understand is: if the type is "bool" (according to fmt.Printf()), why isn't it valid to use this directly with if?

Extra context: I went to the trouble of asking this because it's taken me a long time to get to this point as it is, and since I couldn't really find any search hits including docopt, hopefully an answer here will help the next person :)

The type is not bool, it is an empty interface, which is why you need to assert the correct type. Look at the function signature, ParseDoc returns map[string]any

also: you will note that xx.(bool) is a type assertion, which is not the same as bool(xx), a conversion. Type assertions apply only to interface values and are run-time statements -- they apply runtime checks before "casting" the value to the asserted type -- while conversions may apply to any value, and are validated and evaluated at compile time.

docopt.ParseDoc returns (Opts, error) and Opts is map[string]interface{}, so opts["--debug"] has the type interface{} or any.
Since everything implements any, this value is comparable to everything:

A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T can be compared if type X is comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.

So you can do (Go Playground):
    var debug any = true

    fmt.Printf("Type: %T\n", debug)

    debugTrue := debug == true
    debugTrueString := debug == "true"

    fmt.Println(debug, debugTrue, debugTrueString)

if statements require a boolean expression. While you can compare a variable of type any to a boolean and debug == true is a boolean expression, debug of type any isn't. debugTrueis a boolean, and debugTrue == "true" is not a valid expression.
Also, since type assertions are only valid on interfaces and you can do opts["--debug"].(bool), it is clear that opts["--debug"] must be of interface type.
